# How to download itextpdf in java?

Tags: java, itext

I have to do some verification in my interface and if all go right I download pdf report with itextPdf.

```
@PostMapping("/calcul")
    public String check(BindingResult bindingResult,@RequestParam(value = "action") String action) {
    rechargeService.validate();
    return "interface";
}



public ResponseEntity<Resource> generatePdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        petTransactionRepository.RechargeDetails(reference);
        
        String filename = MessageFormat.format("Recharge-{0}.pdf", reference);
        try {
            InputStreamResource file = PDF.write();
            return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=" + filename)
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf")).body(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
        
    }


    public static InputStreamResource write() throws DocumentException, IOException {

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 50f, 30f);
        
        
        document.open();
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Phrase(" welcome ", font));
        document.add(p);

        document.close();

        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
        return new InputStreamResource(is);
    }
```

When I click in my button and calcul done, I dont get my pdf downloaded. Any idea ?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433228/read-pdf-file-and-offer-it-as-download-with-itext

Comment: Your generatePdf does not have @GetMapping annotation, also it may return `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>`

Comment: What is the `os` in your `write()` method? And you don't associate any `PdfWriter` with your `Document`, so you create no PDF.

Comment: @MedElgarnaoui So how can I edit my function to download pdf ?

Comment: @crystophercr take a look at the solution

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have o lot of errors, it does not compile correctly, and you did not have a resource to download the pdf.

So I write this solution, Take a look at it:

```
@RestController
public class PdfController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pdfreport", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> citiesReportc() throws IOException, DocumentException {

        String filename = MessageFormat.format("Recharge-{0}.pdf", "test");
        
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = write();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; "+filename);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(bis));
    }
    
    public static ByteArrayInputStream write() throws DocumentException, IOException {

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 50f, 30f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
        document.open();
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Phrase(" welcome "));
        document.add(p);

        document.close();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

**Result:**
[image]